# Apache cordova application for windows mobile

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-7

I am trying to create a apache cordova application for all smart phones. I want to know which version of Microsoft visual studio with MSDN is needed to create windows app. Is it MSDN Ultimate or MSDN pro or MSDN Premium.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try VS 2013 CTP which is having builtin support for Cordova apps. And in VS 15 they will come with WP7,WP8 and Android simulator built in to the IDE.

But for simple cordova applications better create the app through CLI and open it in VS. Yes VS is best for JS.

Comment: which version of VS 15 they have this feature .? Is it MSDN Ultimate or MSDN pro or MSDN Premium ?

Comment: You can refer this link http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/cordova-vs.aspx and http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675